# Variance estimation question and unbiasedness.

Tags: calculus, probability, estimation, variance

Hello I have a problem with variance estimation for RQMC.

I have  $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ Sobol points. A randomised set $\tilde{\mathfrak{X}}$ is generated by the random variable $\epsilon$.
For a randomised set $\tilde{\mathfrak{X}}_i$ we construct a RQMC estimate:
\begin{equation}
RQMC_{j,n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tilde{\mathfrak{X}}_{i,j})
\end{equation}
for $0<j \leqslant r$, where $r$ is the total number of different pseudo-random sequences. Then, $RQMC_{r,n}$ estimation equals: 
\begin{equation}
RQMC_{r,n}=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=1}^r RQMC_{j,n}.
\end{equation}
By independence of the samples we have that:
\begin{equation}
Var(RQMC_{r,n})=\frac{ Var(RQMC_{j,n})}{r}.
\end{equation}

I assume that we have this, because of the unbiasedness:
\begin{equation*}
Var(RQMC_{r,n})=Var(\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=1}^rRQMC_{j,n})=\frac{1}{r^2}\sum_{j=1}^rVar(RQMC_{j,n})=\frac{1}{r^2}rVar(RQMC_{j,n})=\frac{1}{r}Var(RQMC_{j,n}).
\end{equation*}

However, we have the following variance estimation:
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{Var}(RQMC_{r,n})=\frac{1}{r(r-1)} \sum_{j=1}^r \Big( RQMC_{j,n}-RQMC_{r,n}\Big)^2\ .
\end{equation*}

So I conclude that we have the following unbiased estimator for $RQMC_{j,n}$:
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{Var}(RQMC_{j,n})=\frac{1}{(r-1)} \sum_{j=1}^r \Big( RQMC_{j,n}-RQMC_{r,n}\Big)^2\ .
\end{equation*}

MY PROBLEM IS: that I don't really understand all the steps to obtain $\widehat{Var}(RQMC_{j,n})$ estimation.

It seems that we should use an unbiased estimator of the population variance here:
$$
S^2=\frac{1}{r-1}\sum_{j=1}^r(X_j-\bar X)^2
$$

I will really appreciate your help and hints.